# Amazon Alexa's in skill purchasing upsell is not working

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am implementing isp and I found that my upsell message is not working in the log it shows upsell message not defined. 
Here is a piece of code I tried:

```js
    const HintIntentHandler = {
     canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HintIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
    const locale = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.locale;
    const ms = handlerInput.serviceClientFactory.getMonetizationServiceClient();

    // Determine if the customer has purchased the hint_pack
    return ms.getInSkillProducts(locale).then(function(res) {
      var product = res.inSkillProducts.filter(record => record.referenceName === 'hint_pack');
 if (isEntitled(product)) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .reprompt(sessionAttributes.currentRiddle.question)
          .withSimpleCard('Level Up Riddles', speechText)
          .getResponse();
      } else {
        const upsellMessage = "You don't currently own the hint pack. Want to learn more about it?";

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .addDirective({
            'type': 'Connections.SendRequest',
            'name': 'Upsell',
            'payload': {
              'InSkillProduct': {
                'productId': product[0].productId
              },
              'upsellMessage': upsellMessage
            },
            'token': 'correlationToken'
          })
          .getResponse();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

and I am using auto delegation for other purposes.
here is the error

```
    "name": "Upsell",
    "payload": {
        "purchaseResult": "ERROR",
        "productId": "amzn1.adg.product.214ce17e-f466-4b08-9afa-215954c297ac",
        "message": "Upsell was not presented."
    },
    "token": "correlationToken"
```

Comment: Is this is really the code that you use? I see that there is `else`, but there is no `if` clause. Other than that, upsell response seems to be correct. Do you get any error messages? What response do you see in dev console when testing this?

Comment: I have if statement I have removed because it has long code in it and I get error message upsell is not defined

Comment: It sounds like you have a variable 'upsell' somewhere, but it is not defined. Can you check that and make sure that 'upsell' variable exists if it is used anywhere? What response does alexa give when you get this error? I feel like the problem might be in the if statement, because this piece of code looks fine to me.

Comment: I have defined upsell as a global variable I use auto delegation maybe that's a problem and I have edited the code above and I am implementing this repo https://github.com/alexa-labs/skill-sample-nodejs-level-up-riddles